# MySQL: How to store a file into a medium blob field binary with HEX

Tags: php, mysql, binary, hex, blob

I have wrote a simple VFS (Virtual File System) in PHP (StreamWrapper) that puts it's data into a MySQL database. The field that stores the data is a medium blob.

Things you can do for example in PHP:

```
copy( 'mytext.txt', 'dbfs://mytext.txt' );
copy( 'mytext.pdf', 'dbfs://mytext.pdf' ); or visa versa/etc.
```

The problem is binary data such as a pdf to pass thru a SQL statement. Escaping, unquoting, base64 etc ruin the data or take too much memory (overhead), for example base64 takes 3x the space.

The best thing to do is, i think, is make it a hex string (only twice the space) that will be stored in the database as binary (no overhead). I have seen the HEX command of MySQL but can't get it to work like I want.

For example, the next statement does not store it as binary data into the blob:

```
UPDATE dbfs SET data=0xFF883838<very long string>FFA9999...... WHERE (fid=<number>)
```

The function I made:

```
private function writeFile( $fid, &$uData = null, $iFileSize = null )
{ 
 $sSql = 'UPDATE '.self::$dbTableNameFat.
         ' SET data="'.(($uData !== null)?('0x'.bin2hex($uData)):null).'"'.
     ',size="'.((int)$iFileSize).'" WHERE ( fid="'.$fid.'" );';
 return $this->writeQuery( $sSql ); 
}
```

The blob contains the data but in HEX format and not in binary. How can I achieve the behaviour I want?

Comment: Use a prepared query with placeholders and binary data will pass through without requiring any encodingl

Comment: I understand but is not possible because of the way the PHP wrapper works, it is a stream handler. The stream wrapper does not know what is happening outside.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP stream handlers, but I don't understand why that would prevent using mysqli or PDO prepared queries.

Comment: For example: the source filename I want to copy is not known inside the wrapper. The wrapper only handles the stream to write (destination).

Comment: If you have enough information to create `$sSql` as a string, you should be able to perform the same query with placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a prepared query. I'll use PDO-style syntax.

```
private function writeFile($fid, &$uData = null, $iFileSize = null) {
    $stmt = $this->prepare(
        "UPDATE " . self::$dbTableNameFat .
        " SET data = :data, size = :size WHERE fid = :fid");
    $stmt->execute(array( 'data' => $uData,
                          'size' => $iFileSize,
                          'fid' => $fid
                        );
};
```

PDO documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Interesting, thanks, but where does the prepareQuery came from?

Comment: You need to add it to your class. It calls the PDO `prepare()` method.

Comment: Is this an extension? Is it enabled by default on mosts hosts?

Comment: Yes, I expect it's available on most hosts. The mysql extension is deprecated, everyone should be migrating to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: AHA, very good info, thanks again. I will play with it. I have extend the class already with PDO.

Comment: PDO's prepareQuery is undefined? With what class do I extend my class? Now i have CDBFS extends PDO but doens't seem right. Any suggestions?

Comment: The PDO method is called `prepare`. I've added a link to the PDO documentation to the answer.

Comment: You're going to have to completely rewrite all the database-related parts of your class, to use PDO instead of mysql.

Comment: It is working now, nice! But, it seems to be a bit slow? is that correct? It takes two seconds to 'upload'/copy a file of 100kb.

Comment: Preparing the query is an extra database operation. If you can cache the prepared statement in the class and and reuse it, that might help.

Comment: Why did you change `$this->prepareQuery` to `$this->prepare`? I did it intentionally, to distinguish between the methods belonging to your class and the methods belonging to PDO. It's analogous to the `writeQuery()` in your original code, which presumably calls `mysql_query()` internally.

Comment: And why did you change `$uData` to a reference parameter? The function never updates it, so there's no need for a reference. If you think it's to save data copying, that's not necessary -- PHP uses copy-on-write optimization.

Comment: I think this topic is not about how to code i guess. I change the function name because prepareQuery doesn't exists, prepare does. I change the $uData to reference because it saves an extra copy. If you don't believe that it doesn't make sense you are wrong (test it). Also the declaration of the array adds another copy, so there are three copies of the same thing. And, don't trust the code optimalization of PHP, if you can do it yourself you will understand better what is happening.

Comment: `prepareQuery` exists if you make it exist -- remember, `$this` is an instance of YOUR class, not PDO. See http://hengrui-li.blogspot.de/2011/08/php-copy-on-write-how-php-manages.html regarding PHP's copy-on-write mechanism.

Comment: I don't get the problem, sure. If you just go to wrap something because of a name does not make sense to me.